# I can't get selenium-webdriver with chromedriver working on Mac OSX

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to do some functional testing using selenium-webdriver in **Google Chrome** navigator on **Mac OSX**, but I have problems while trying to interact with the navigator.

I've simplified the problem into a similar one: I need to open the Google main page and write something in its input, so I execute this node script:

```
require('chromedriver');

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .forBrowser('chrome')
    .build();

driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');
driver.findElement(By.name('q')).sendKeys('webdriver');
```

The npm dependencies are:

```
npm install selenium-webdriver chromedriver
```

The results of the execution are: the Google Chrome browser opens (so the chromedriver *seems to work*), but the input field isn't written, because **the get call never finishes executing**. So the browser can load a given web page but after that I can't interact with it.

Of course, I've also tried to download and install manually the [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html), locating the binary file in `/usr/local/bin` and `chmod +x` it, but the result is the same.

However, if I try the same in Safari (removing the first `require` line and using `'safari'` for browser instead of `'chrome'`) it works! But I need to test it in Google Chrome!

Also, I have tryied the same example using Java and Google Chrome, and it works! It's a problem related with the selenium webdriver Javascript implementation? Or its integration with chromedriver...?

Answer (score 0):

WebDriverJs uses promises in order to make dealing with async code.
Take a look here for a more in-depth clarification / example: http://www.codechewing.com/library/beginners-guide-to-selenium-webdriverjs/

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com/ncr');

driver.findElement({name: 'q'}).then(function(input) {
  input.sendKeys('webdriver');
  input.sendKeys(WebDriver.Key.ENTER);
});
```